# Diagnostic Updater Constructor and Nodelets

Tags: ros, diagnostics, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a really difficult time using Diagnostic Updater.  In general, the DiagnosedPublisher constructor is very strict and requires:

[DiagnosedPublisher](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/diagnostic_updater/html/classdiagnostic__updater_1_1DiagnosedPublisher.html) (const ros::Publisher &pub, diagnostic_updater::Updater &diag, const diagnostic_updater::FrequencyStatusParam &freq, const diagnostic_updater::TimeStampStatusParam &stamp)

which [FrequenceyStatusParam](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/diagnostic_updater/html/structdiagnostic__updater_1_1FrequencyStatusParam.html) requires: FrequencyStatusParam (double *min_freq, double *max_freq, double tolerance=0.1, int window_size=5)

and [TimeStampStatusParam](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/diagnostic_updater/html/structdiagnostic__updater_1_1TimeStampStatusParam.html) optionally requires: TimeStampStatusParam (const double min_acceptable=-1, const double max_acceptable=5)

And even worse, the [diagnostic_updater::Updater](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/diagnostic_updater/html/classdiagnostic__updater_1_1Updater.html) seems to make its own Nodehandle, so you'll have to call init before declaring it.

It seems to be impossible to have one of these as a global variable outside of a class (example, in a C++ file with just a main and a few functions wrapping a non-ROS library).  The only reasonable approach here seems to be keeping the diagnostics declarations within main and running with a `while(ros::ok()){ros::spinOnce();}` loop.

It also seems extremely difficult to initialize a DiagnosedPublisher member inside of a nodelet in an initialization list.  This needs access to the nodehandle, but you cannot call getMTNodeHandle() or getMTPrivateNodeHandle() until the onInit() function in the nodelet.

Does anyone have a experience running diagnostics in these situations (or even better an example script and nodelet that use diagnostics)?

It's also possible that there are less-strict alternatives that I did not see looking through the API.

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11616/diagnostic-updater-constructor-and-nodelets/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2011-10-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try allocating it as a new class member pointer inside your `onInit()`?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-10-25**:
Thanks Jack!  The eventual, super easy solution was to use a boost shared pointer, and reset or make shared in the onInit.  This is what I get for learning Java first years ago.  ;)